# Python LDAP3 - how to get results entries into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to get results from the Python3 (3.9) module LDAP3 into a Pandas DataFrame, so I can manipulate with the content better.

I can perform a simple:

```
for entry in conn.entries:
  print(str(entry.enter_raw_attributes))
```

Here are example printed results:

```
{'sAMAccountName': [b'username1'], 'mail': [b'Jane.Doe@organisation.org']}
{'sAMAccountName': [b'username2'], 'mail': [b'Frank.Doe@organisation.org']}
{'sAMAccountName': [b'username3'], 'mail': [b'Mark.Doe@organisation.org']}
{'sAMAccountName': [b'username4'], 'mail': []}
```

What I would like to see in a Pandas Dataframe is the following:

```
{
  "sAMAccountName": [username1, username2, username3, username4],
  "mail": [Jane.Doe@organisation.org, Frank.Doe@organisation.org, Mark.Doe@organisation.org, NaN]
}

     sAMAccountName  mail
  0       username1        Jane.Doe@organisatiin.org
  1       username2        Frank.Doe@organisation.org
  2       username3        Mark.Doe@organisation.org
  3.      username4
```

- I struggled with appending lists of dictionaries and all sorts, but all failed.
- I see the offending 'b' popping up in front of the values which also needs to be removed (e.g. b'username1' or b'Mark.Doe@organisation.org').
- I am not sure how to set NaN (null) values for missing emails in the DataFrame

I would appreciate help to get me off the ground on getting the Pandas DataFrame properly populated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

b' indicates it is a byte-string and is the result of requesting the enter_raw_attributes.

You may want to call the attributes you are looking for directly, or convert it to another data type that can be digested.

Here's an example in the [documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_abstraction_reader.html) of different ways to work with the returned data:

```py
>>> # get the DN of an entry
>>> r[0].entry_dn
'cn=b.young,ou=ldap3-tutorial,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org'

>>> # query the attributes in the Entry as a list of names
>>> r[0].entry_attributes
['destinationIndicator', 'x500UniqueIdentifier', 'audio', 'photo', 'uid', 'l', 'pager', 'carLicense', 'street', 'teletexTerminalIdentifier', 'o', 'st', 'homePostalAddress', 'preferredDeliveryMethod', 'roomNumber', 'sn', 'homePhone', 'x121Address', 'displayName', 'userSMIMECertificate', 'userPassword', 'title', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'mail', 'initials', 'ou', 'businessCategory', 'seeAlso', 'jpegPhoto', 'registeredAddress', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'postalAddress', 'telephoneNumber', 'mobile', 'labeledURI', 'postalCode', 'objectClass', 'employeeNumber', 'secretary', 'employeeType', 'description', 'cn', 'userCertificate', 'userPKCS12', 'postOfficeBox', 'departmentNumber', 'givenName', 'internationalISDNNumber', 'preferredLanguage', 'telexNumber', 'manager']

>>> # query the attributes in the Entry as a dict of key/value pairs
>>> r[0].entry_attributes_as_dict
{'destinationIndicator': [], 'x500UniqueIdentifier': [], 'audio': [], 'photo': [], 'uid': [], 'l': [], 'pager': [], 'carLicense': [], 'street': [], 'teletexTerminalIdentifier': [], 'o': [], 'homePostalAddress': [], 'preferredDeliveryMethod': [], 'roomNumber': [], 'st': [], 'homePhone': [], 'x121Address': [], 'displayName': [], 'userSMIMECertificate': [], 'userPassword': [], 'title': [], 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName': [], 'mail': [], 'preferredLanguage': [], 'initials': [], 'internationalISDNNumber': [], 'ou': [], 'businessCategory': [], 'seeAlso': [], 'jpegPhoto': [], 'registeredAddress': [], 'facsimileTelephoneNumber': [], 'postalAddress': [], 'telephoneNumber': ['1111'], 'mobile': [], 'labeledURI': [], 'postalCode': [], 'objectClass': ['inetOrgPerson', 'organizationalPerson', 'person', 'top'], 'employeeNumber': [], 'description': [], 'employeeType': [], 'secretary': [], 'cn': ['b.young'], 'userPKCS12': [], 'postOfficeBox': [], 'departmentNumber': ['DEV'], 'givenName': ['Beatrix'], 'sn': ['Young'], 'userCertificate': [], 'telexNumber': [], 'manager': []}


>>> # let's check which attributes are mandatory
>>> r[0].entry_mandatory_attributes
['sn', 'objectClass', 'cn']

>>> # convert the Entry to LDIF
>>> print(r[0].entry_to_ldif())
version: 1
dn: cn=b.young,ou=ldap3-tutorial,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
sn: Young
telephoneNumber: 1111
cn: b.young
departmentNumber: DEV
givenName: Beatrix
# total number of entries: 1

>>> print(r[0].entry_to_json(include_empty=False))  # Use include_empty=True to include empty attributes
{
    "attributes": {
        "cn": [
            "b.young"
        ],
        "departmentNumber": [
            "DEV"
        ],
        "givenName": [
            "Beatrix"
        ],
        "objectClass": [
            "inetOrgPerson",
            "organizationalPerson",
            "person",
            "top"
        ],
        "sn": [
            "Young"
        ],
        "telephoneNumber": [
            "1111"
        ]
    },
    "dn": "cn=b.young,ou=ldap3-tutorial,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org"
}
```